# proguard: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, proguard, concurrentmodification

Proguard causes java.util.ConcurrentModificationException for a loop:

```
Map map = ...
for (Object value: map.values()) {    <----- this line cause exception
    // use the value, not modifying the map
}
```

The code does not modify the map during the loop, and it works fine
without proguard.

Disabling optimization resolved it.

```
-dontoptimize
```

Any solution if optimization is on?

Comment: Show the body of the loop. That line isn't modifying anything, although it may be where the exception is thrown.

Comment: More likely than not, you're adding elements to or removing them from the map inside the loop.

Comment: No. it works fine without proguard.

Comment: @Sunnyday it doesn't necessarily "work fine". ConcurrentModificationExceptions are thrown on a best-effort basis, i.e. they are not guaranteed to be thrown when concurrent modification occurs. *Show your code*.